# Android obfuscate doesn't change package name

Tags: android, obfuscation

After I update android studio to 3.5 version, When I sign and make APK from my app, I can't hide my libraries package names. But in the old version, it worked completely fine.

My proguard file content:

```
-repackageclasses 'obf'
-allowaccessmodification
```

The content of obfuascated package names just is R file (That obfuscated). All of others files hidden in 'obf' directory.

[image]

But I want hidden my package names completely.

My package names are:

```
- com.aminbahrami.abpuihelper
- com.aminbahrami.abpjson
- com.aminbahrami.abputility
- com.aminbahrami.abpbarcodereader
- com.aminbahrami.abpwebservice
- ir.aminbahrami.libs.***
```

Comment: Nobody can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

The problem was in one of my used dependencies.

One of the dependencies that I used, was this code in proguard file.

```
-keep class !**.R
-keep class !**.R$* {
    <fields>;
}
```

This library is not my library. So I can't edit and remove the above code from proguard file.

So problem was above code in proguard file (That was is the external library)